# Query mysql - results unexpected

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT results.data_scrap AS data_badania,
  tests.data_test AS data_badania2,
  results.words_count_out_a AS liczba_slow,
  results.position AS pozycja
FROM results,
  tests,
  keywords
WHERE results.keyword=test
AND tests.id=1
ORDER BY results.position
```

I got this query, I don`t know why, but in my results one row is repeated several times.

```
SELECT *
FROM results,
  tests,
  keywords
WHERE results.keyword=test
AND tests.id=1
ORDER BY results.position
```

The result is `1.1.1.1.1.2.2.2.2.2.3.3.3.3.3` instead of `1.2.3`.

Comment: You are not joining the keywords table with anohter table so you probably have 5 keywords in that table which gives you 5 results.

Comment: use group by or show your table schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM results,
     tests,
     keywords
WHERE results.keyword=test
AND tests.id=1
ORDER BY results.position
```

Alternatively, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM results,
     tests,
     keywords
WHERE results.keyword=test
AND tests.id=1
GROUP BY results.position
```